# SQL Table Valued Function - Return certain data from 'WITH' based on parameter value

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, case-when

I am trying to do a "with" to loop through some data (which its doing fine). But after that with, I want to return data dependent on a bit parameter. Its important that this is inside a function. Below is basically what my code is doing.

```
WITH StuffChain 
AS (
   //initial
    union all
   //more
)
```

After this, I am trying to do something like

```
CASE WHEN @MyParamVal = 1 THEN
      SELECT TOP (1) * FROM StuffChain
ELSE
      SELECT * FROM StuffChain
END
RETURN
```

SQL is not my strength and I am still learning sorry. I am also unsure whether or not to use inline or multi statement function

EDIT: When I am giving the case, I am using it to explain what I am after to return, not necessarily what I will use. I use it to just describe what I need using what little I know if that makes sense.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: I will give that a read although I am struggling to understand why I need to provide sample data examples when my question is only asking about how to return all rows or just one row of data

Comment: A `WITH` isn't a "loop". What you have there is a Common Table Expression (CTE), or more specifically a recursive CTE (rCTE). These aren't the same as loops (I.e. a `WHILE`). You also appear to be thinking that `CASE` is a statement in T-SQL; it isn't it's a `CASE` **expression**. It doesn't change the logical flow of the statement, it returns a **scalar** value.

Comment: For what you have here, the reason you're getting an error is because you're trying to use `CASE` as a statement, not as an expression, and a CTE can only be referenced in the **statement** it is declared (because it is also an expression). You can't declare a CTE earlier in the batch and then reference it later; that would be similar to declaring a column in a statement and then expecting the be able to reference that column in a later statement in the same batch.

Comment: @Tanya providing sample data and expected results means that someone attempting to answer your question can verify that their solution does indeed provide you with a working answer. It also gives you a chance to verify that your logic is indeed correct as it is very easy to attempt to simplify your logic for the question and get it wrong.

Comment: Sorry @Larnu I used the wrong terminology. I know it is CTE. I guess for now I am sort of thinking of it as a "loop" as it starts and goes through data and returns what I need. I am still researching and learning about it. All this is so helpful

Comment: Indeed an rCTE does recurse through data (hence the name), so it does appear *similar* to a loop, so I can understand why someone would think of it as such.

Comment: Thank you for your comments to correct me, its helpful at the moment. I wasnt clear in my post sorry, when I use the "case", I am just describing what I need using what I know in basic terms as I am not sure what I need to use for my issue. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows. This is just one of the solution. you can do with many other ways also.

```
WITH StuffChain 
AS (
   //initial
    union all
   //more
)
```

After creation of CTE, try with following

```
SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN @MyParamVal = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM StuffChain) END  *
FROM StuffChain
order by <column> <ASC/DESC>;
```

Comment: This is perfect! Simple and clear cut and I can do an order by after stuff chain. Thank you so much!

Comment: WC :) though other answers given here are also sql friendly queries.

Comment: I have given them a try and they dont seem to work for the function I have. It wont let me create a temporary table or table varilable within either type of table function. And I am getting errors for the other one

Comment: Nice answer +1 but note that you should at least suggest using an `ORDER BY` clause, without which `TOP` does not make much sense.

Comment: SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN @MyParamVal= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM StuffChain) END ) * FROM StuffChain e ORDER BY e.MyColName DESC;

That is the final code @TimBiegeleisen so there is an order by but its after the CTE. This way, it makes sense in the context of the real code

Answer (score 5):

First of all, using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is somewhat meaningless, because it provides no order against which to select the first few rows.  In this case, we can try using `ROW_NUMBER` to control the ordering:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) rn
    FROM StuffChain
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE
    (rn = @MyParamVal) OR (@MyParamVal <> 1);
```

Comment: I am so sorry, I am confused. StuffChain was a CTE and and now we putting that cte inside another cte?

Comment: @Tanya move the row_number function inside your CTE then apply the same logic.

Comment: @Tanya There is nothing at all wrong with putting a CTE into another CTE. If something in my answer be unclear, then ask. Note that it isn't possible to build a TOP clause using a variable without dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks so far for your help. I am trying to put your answer into my own CTE but mine as a union all in between and I am confused how it fits in with that. Based on what I know of a CTE, Im confused as well how you can have an order by inside one based on its nature. It is complaining about a "multi part identifier could not be found"

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't offer much help.  But if you have doubts about the code I did post, I'm happy to comment.

Comment: I have found another works for mine best. Thank you for your efforts though. I struggled to get yours to work for my issue

Comment: Why not? I wanted to return top 1 row or return all all rows depending on the bit value of a function parameter and I feel like that fulfills what I need. I can do an order by as well on the select statement. Was there wording in my question which asked for something else? Apologies if thats the case

Comment: I had no idea that `TOP` allows this syntax.  It would not work with `LIMIT` on other databases.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a Table Variable e.g. `Declare @TEMP Table (intcol int,...)` inside a function.

```
Declare @TEMP Table (intcol int,...)

WITH StuffChain 
AS (
   //initial
    union all
   //more
)
SELECT * INTO @TEMP FROM StuffChain;

--do what ever you want with temp table
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but the temporary tables dont seem to work within functions. At least not for my issue

Comment: ahh apologize me, i mean you can use table variable with @sign

Comment: I tried that also and it still complained I'm afraid

Comment: look at this sample: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-function-in-SQL-Server-Example-Function-to-Split-Comma-separated-Delimited-string-in-SQL-Server-2005-2008-and-2012.aspx

Comment: My error when trying to make a temp table or temp table variable is "Incorrect syntax near 'DECLARE' Expecting '(', SELECT OR WITH"